# Why don't the title tags display from this XML document with XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xml-parsing

I've downloaded this [books.xml](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml) file from W3Schools, and I've parsed it with the code below ([with instructions from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp)), but the title tags don't appear in the parsed code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    this.responseText;
    console.log("Up to this line works.");
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "books.xml", true);
xhttp.send();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get the title tags to appear in the result too?

Comment: [While W3Schools is better than it used to be, it is still a resource packed full of bad practises and security problems. It is best avoided.](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling the browser to treat the XML as HTML … which it isn't.

Most of the elements in the XML do not exist in HTML so error recovery sticks them into the document with default styling.

HTML does have a `<title>` element. It controls the default bookmark name and is displayed in the browser's title bar and is used to label the tab (this may vary between browsers). The `<title>` element isn't rendered in the document, so its default styling is `display: none`.

```js
var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("div title"));
console.log(style.getPropertyValue("display"));
```

```html
<div>This is an invalid <title>title</title> element.</div>
```

You would have to write CSS to change that if you wanted it to display.

A better bet would be to read the data out of the XML and generate real, semantic HTML.